How do I see the problematic call in the call stack when calling an Invoke method with C#
I have a multi threaded C# Windows Forms application that occasionally crashes after several hours.
Im running it in visual studio 2019, x64 Debug mode
When it crashes, the program pointer is on Application.Run(new MainForm()).
The call stack is shown below
I cannot trace it back to the calling function.
Since the crash is a DynamicInvokeImpl, it seems logical its caused by one of the many Invocation calls to another function or object.
But the call stack does not seem to point to where this invocation was called from, so I have no idea how to trace it back.
The actual error is "IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array."
How do I trace this error to its source?
Why can't I see the calling function in the call stack?
Is there any way I can see the call stack on the thread that created the invoke call?
I have Just My Code disabled
I tried the Windows->Threads window, and switched between every thread. Only one of them shows another call stack, but none of the calls come from any of my functions.


I can't answer your question, but the type and message of the exception makes me think that the UI thread tries to read a List<T> (or Dictionary<K,V>) that is concurrently mutated on another thread. You may want to do an investigation in that direction.

Where did you get the actual error from? That looks like an exception object, did its stack trace look the same as in your image? Any inner exceptions on it? Did you disable "just my code" in your debug session? Otherwise run your app from perfview: https://github.com/microsoft/perfview as that has an option to capture exception stacks.

Is your problem solved? Can you provide more detailed error message or  sample code?
